# Ninject.Extensions.Interception intercept parameter constructor

Tags: c#, constructor, ninject

Bindings:

```
IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel();
kernel.Bind<ILog>().ToMethod(context => LogManager.GetLogger(context.Request.Target.Type));
kernel.Bind<TSyncService>().ToSelf().Intercept().With<TimingInterceptor>();
ISyncService syncService = kernel.Get<TSyncService>();
```

Consumption:

```
public class TSyncService:ISyncService
{
    ILog log;
    public TSyncService(ILog log)
    {
        this.log = log;
    }
```

Problem:

**Ninject** can't **inject** into the **dynamic proxy constructor** `'TSyncService(ILog log)'`